# Check which fields are changed in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model with many fields. I need to run a code only when two specific fields are changed. I know I can modify my model's `save()` method but I don't know how to check which fields are changed in my `ModelForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry because i cant give you any code snippet since i am not very experienced in Django, but i would go for getting a signal when a change is done through a controler class listening on the models and hearing for changes. Hope i might helped a bit.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[Django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils) has something called a [FieldTracker](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker) that does exactly this.  Just instantiate it in your model and tell it to track the specific fields you're looking for.  Then you can use the [has_changed](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#has-changed) method to test if a given field has changed since the last save.

This package has some other great utilities as well, I really recommend looking through the [docs](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/smn/django-dirtyfields).